# How to write vectorized functions that pull arguments from two dataframes of different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am putting together a new formatted dataframe that aggregates data from a different dataframe. I need to create a column in this new dataframe that filters and aggregates data from a secondary dataframe. I wrote a function to do so which filters the second dataframe based on the new column title and and the values from each row of another column in the new dataframe. The function then sums the values of a column in the secondary dataframe.

As an example.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alan','sky','liam','liam','alan','liam','alan','sky','bryan','alan','sky']
                   ,'age': [1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]
                   ,'values': [564,65,4,44,8,60,4,684,51,3,14]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alan','sky','liam','bryan']})

def get_cumsum_values(person,data,col):
    value = data[data.apply(lambda x: x.age < col and x.name == person, axis = 1)].values.sum()
    return value

df1['10'] = df1.apply(lambda x: get_cumsum_values(person = x.name, data = df1, col = 10))
```

Dealing with a ton of data, and this code takes forever. The culprit seems to be the apply method at the end to create the new column. Is there a way to use vectorization to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like the following (without any `.apply`s):

```
def get_cumsum_values(names, age, data):
    return (
        data[data.name.isin(names) & (data.age < age)]
        .groupby("name")["values"]
        .sum()
        .rename(str(age))
        .reset_index(drop=False)
    )

df1 = df1.merge(
    get_cumsum_values(df1.name.unique(), 10, df2), on="name", how="left"
)
```

Result:

```
    name     10
0   alan  564.0
1    sky   65.0
2   liam    NaN
3  bryan    NaN
```

Or, you set the `name` column of `df1` as index, and then do

```
df1 = df1.set_index("name")

def get_cumsum_values(names, age, data):
    return (
        data[data.name.isin(names) & (data.age < age)]
        .groupby("name")["values"]
        .sum()
    )

df1['10'] = get_cumsum_values(df1.index.unique(), 10, df2)
df1['35'] = get_cumsum_values(df1.index.unique(), 35, df2)
```

Result:

```
          10     35
name               
alan   564.0  576.0
sky     65.0   65.0
liam     NaN  108.0
bryan    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: @jezebel If this was helpful please consider accepting/upvoting (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).